# eclipse compiles generic private access, javac not

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, compiler-construction, javac

Consider the following simple class:

```
public class Bean {

    private int i;

    public static <T extends Bean> void o(T t) {
        System.out.println(t.i);
    }

}
```

In Eclipse, this just compiles fine. But with javac, i got the following error:

```
Bean.java:8: error: i has private access in Bean
       System.out.println(t.i);
                           ^
```

Is this a bug in Eclipse compiler? And why i cannot access `i` in this way? If i remove generics, this compiles fine with javac, too.

EDIT: It seems the problem is with m2e (maven eclipse integration). A simple eclipse project does not reproduce this problem. I use m2e 1.4

Comment: What Eclipse version are you on? Kepler doesn't have this issue.

Comment: fwiw, eclipse Juno shows a compilation error. Just use a getter here

Comment: Hmm. This is an eclipse maven project (m2e 1.4). A simple eclipse project does not have this issue.